# splitting JSON file using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have below big json file

```
    {
        "sections": [
            {
                "facts": [
                    {
                        "name": "Server",
                        "value": "<https://xxxxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/v1_allagents>"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Environment",
                        "value": "dev"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Issue",
                        "value": "Server is [EDITED]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "facts": [
                    {
                        "name": "Server",
                        "value": "<https://xxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/customer-characterstics-v1>"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Environment",
                        "value": "dev"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Issue",
                        "value": "Server is [STOPPED]"
                    }
                ]
            }
{'facts': 
    [
    {'name': 'Server', 'value': u'<https://xxxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/soap-post-v1_relations>'}, 
    {'name': 'Environment', 'value': u'dev'}, {'name': 'Issue', 'value': u' status is [STOPPED]'}
    ]
}, 
{'facts': 
    [
    {'name': 'Server', 'value': u'<https://xxxxxxx.134:18443/collector/pipeline/characterstics-v1_allagents>'}, 
    {'name': 'Environment', 'value': u'dev'}, {'name': 'Issue', 'value': u' status is [EDITED]'}
    ]
}, 
{'facts': 
    [
    {'name': 'Server', 'value': u'<https://xxxxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/ab23-8128b7c9fcf2>'}, 
    {'name': 'Environment', 'value': u'dev'}, {'name': 'Issue', 'value': u'status is [EDITED]'}
    ]
}
     ]
    }
    ....
```

now I'm struggling to split above file as below and dump into another new files:

```
{
    "text": "Status",
    "themeColor": "#FF0000",
    {
        "sections": [
            {
                "facts": [
                    {
                        "name": "Server",
                        "value": "<https://xxxxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/v1_allagents>"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Environment",
                        "value": "dev"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Issue",
                        "value": "Server is [EDITED]"
                    }
                ]
            }
     ]
    }
}
```

what I could able to achieve so far is print each tags under facts, but not the way I expect as above.

so, I'm having trouble adding those extra lines prior the final ones and then dump it to another file.
How should I approach this? not using JQ.
each splitted file should have same header and then exactly same pattern for key sections and facts .

edit:

As per Andrej's solution it works perfectly alright for one split at a time.
But how to split the file based on n size, let's say I want to split my original big file where 5 facts exists  2 facts per file.n = 2 
so, it should create 3 json files , where first 2 contains 2 blocks of facts and last one should be only one since that's left.

Then final output should be:

```
 {'text': ' Status', 'themeColor': '#FF0000', 'sections': 
    [
    {'facts': 
        [
        {'name': 'Server', 'value': u'<https://xxxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/soap-post-v1>'},
        {'name': 'Environment', 'value': u'dev'}, 
        {'name': 'Issue', 'value': u' status is [STOPPED]'}
        ]
    }, 
    {'facts': 
        [
        {'name': 'Server', 'value': u'<https://xxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/be9694085a70>'}, 
        {'name': 'Environment', 'value': u'dev'},
        {'name': 'Issue', 'value': u' status is [STOPPED]'}
        ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

and

---

```
  {'text': ' Status', 'themeColor': '#FF0000', 'sections': 
    [
    {'facts': 
        [
        {'name': 'Server', 'value': u'<https://xxxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/soap-post-v1_relations>'}, 
        {'name': 'Environment', 'value': u'dev'}, {'name': 'Issue', 'value': u' status is [STOPPED]'}
        ]
    }, 
    {'facts': 
        [
        {'name': 'Server', 'value': u'<https://xxxxxxx.134:18443/collector/pipeline/characterstics-v1_allagents>'}, 
        {'name': 'Environment', 'value': u'dev'}, {'name': 'Issue', 'value': u' status is [EDITED]'}
        ]
    }
    ]}
```

as per above one block of fact from original file, hence it will create it's own json

```
 {'text': ' Status', 'themeColor': '#FF0000', 'sections': 
    [
    {'facts': 
        [
        {'name': 'Server', 'value': u'<https://xxxxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/ab23-8128b7c9fcf2>'}, 
        {'name': 'Environment', 'value': u'dev'}, {'name': 'Issue', 'value': u'status is [EDITED]'}
        ]
    }
    ]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load the big file json into dictionary using `json` module. Then treat the loaded data as classical Python dict.

If your file contains the string in question, then this example:

```
import json

with open('YOUR_JSON_FILE.json', 'r') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

    for i, fact in enumerate(data['sections'], 1):

        with open('data_out_{}.json'.format(i), 'w') as f_out:
            d = {}
            d['text'] = 'Status'
            d['themeColor'] = '#FF0000'
            d['sections'] = fact
            json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

This creates two files `data_out_1.json` and `data_out_2.json` containing:

```
{
    "text": "Status",
    "themeColor": "#FF0000",
    "sections": {
        "facts": [
            {
                "name": "Server",
                "value": "<https://xxxxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/v1_allagents>"
            },
            {
                "name": "Environment",
                "value": "dev"
            },
            {
                "name": "Issue",
                "value": "Server is [EDITED]"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "text": "Status",
    "themeColor": "#FF0000",
    "sections": {
        "facts": [
            {
                "name": "Server",
                "value": "<https://xxxxx:18443/collector/pipeline/customer-characterstics-v1>"
            },
            {
                "name": "Environment",
                "value": "dev"
            },
            {
                "name": "Issue",
                "value": "Server is [STOPPED]"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT:

To chunk the JSON file, you can use this example:

```
import json

def chunk(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

with open('YOUR_JSON_FILE.json', 'r') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)


for i, fact in enumerate(chunk(data['sections'], 2), 1):  # <-- change 2 to your chunk size
    with open('data_out_{}.json'.format(i), 'w') as f_out:
        d = {}
        d['text'] = 'Status'
        d['themeColor'] = '#FF0000'
        d['sections'] = fact
        json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

Comment: thanks @andrej, but if I want final json with n blocks facts inside, from the large original json. like below, will it be possible? like if I say split the original based on 2 sets, then it it should have final json as combination of your suggested 2 files `data_out_1.json` and `data_out_2.json` but with one text, themeColor and section?

Comment: @ManasSamantaray Can you edit your question and put the input and desired output there?

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

with open('/tmp/json_response_output.json') as datafile:
    datastore = json.load(datafile)

for n, details in enumerate(datastore['sections']):
    split_json = datastore.copy()
    split_json['sections'] = [details]
    with open(f'json_response_output_part{n}.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(split_json, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```